# Cannot try the javascript sample in wso2 identity server

Tags: javascript, wso2

I've followed the instruction on https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/get-started/try-samples/qsg-spa-javascript/ but when i execute the command `npm install && npm start` nothing happen. access localhost:3000 return nothing.

[NodeJS and Npm versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAjCk.png)
[nothing result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzWfT.png)

Can anyone help me? Thank alot.

Comment: The && notation is only for Unix systems.  Since you're on Windows, do those two commands separately.  `npm install` and then `npm start`.

Comment: Thank for reply me. I did it but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Do you have Windows firewall enabled?  You may need to open up that port.

Comment: Thank you. I've opened firewall for that port (port 3000), but the problem is still alive. Is there anyone success with that code?